# EV3 manual recording for displacement

Tags: ev3, python

So I'm doing this project using an EV3, here are the tasks of the project:

- We have to save the path that the robot will take manually ( we will move the robot by hand and it'll save the movements) so we can run it again automatically
- We want the robot so save the map of the room that we move it in

I'm confused about how to do that exactly, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

If your robot has wheels, then measure or calculate the circumference of the wheels. Then you just have to count the rotations of the axle and multiply by the circumference to get the total travelled distance.

<sub>I'm deliberately only giving pointers instead of solutions, since if it's a project with tasks, then you are supposed to learn about it - if you're still stuck, tell us where and how, so we can give you further tips and pointers to help you learn.</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to map the room manually with the robot  and then make it run through the map?

Comment: @MajedM.Alharthi The answer most probably is "Yes, it is". But it depends on the exact parameters of the problem - i.e. what do you mean by "map the room manually", "save the map" and "run through the map". As I wrote in the answer, you can know how long the robot has travelled in one direction. Additionally you can learn if it has rotated in various ways depending on its exact design - most probably if the wheel(s) on one side rotate differently than those on the other side. And if you save the lengths of straight movements, interspersed with the angles turned, then you have the exact route.